# Do electric sinusidal waves rotate 45 degrees too when light pass through a hollow cylindrical magnet or just the sinusoidal magnetic waves do that?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, visible-light

Do electric sinusoidal waves rotate 45 degrees too when light pass through a hollow cylindrical magnet or just the sinusoidal magnetic waves do that?

Answer (score 1):

In an electromagnetic wave, the angle between the electric field vector and the magnetic field vector is always 90º.  Rotation of plane polarization affects both the electric and magnetic fields.